# I changed Postgis Schema Name in QGIS, now my geometry column is corrupted, how do I fix

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I changed name of PostGIS2.5 Schema from **public** to **supervisor** using QGIS 3.2.4;
[image: changing schema name in qgis]

after that I discovered that my data was now unable to display geometry. If you check the geometry column in pgAdmin4, it now reads **"supervisor.geometry"** instead of just, **"geometry"**

See how the geom column looks like
[image: see how the geom column looks like]

when I try to change data type of the column in pgAdmin, its showing that **"geometry"** data type no longer exists, what can be found is **supervisor.geometry**

[image: list of data types now available]

[image: datatype geometry nolonger exists]

Comment: Your screenshots show `"Supervisorrrr"`, not `supervisor` - I assume that's a typo and not the actual topic of your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have logged-in as user Postgres (who can presumably do whatever it wants in the DB) and renamed the public schema and now extensions stored within the public schema are not working anymore.

Honestly, about everything is wrong in this sentence.

Rename it back to `public` - in lower case, that should fix your immediate issue.

Then, decide what you want: have postgis functions in another schema? Prevent creating objects in `public`? Allow creating new object in another schema by default? Move your GIS tables to another schema?

Then read about installing or moving the `Postgis` extension in another schema, about creating new users, about creating a new schema, about granting usage/read/write access to schema and tables to users, about setting the `search_path` etc.

And, last but not least, keep the following two tips in mind:

1. leave the public schema alone (instead, prevent users from using it if you wish)
2. never use a super-user account such as `Postgres` for daily tasks (instead, create different DB users with just enough privileges for their tasks. There is no need to be able to delete the entire DB if the user is supposed to simply read/write to a few tables)

Comment: Renaming the `public` schema should not be a problem in itself (it can be renamed like any other schema), and it should also not cause extensions to break. It sounds more like the OPs client code broke because the new schema name was no longer part of the `search_path`.

Comment: Good point! Renaming a schema does not modify the search_path, which continues to point to the old name

Answer (score 1):

What you used to know as `geometry` was actually `public.geometry` thanks to default [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH) setting (db setting, not an environment variable) of `"$user", public`.

Whenever you referred to a table, type or anything without schema specified, Postgres first checked if there's a schema with the same name as your current user (`"$user"`) and if that object is in there. Then it checked `public` and since it's where PostGIS types and functions are by default, it worked. It actually also checks `pg_catalog` for built-in stuff as well as session-specific `pg_temp_nnn` where your `temp` objects are.

Now that you renamed `public` to `Supervisorrrrr`, `geometry` is no longer in any schema it's checking in `search_path` list. You *could* run

```sql
select set_config( 'search_path'
                  ,(current_setting('search_path')||', "Supervisorrrrr"')
                  ,false);
```

But it's best you change it back to avoid breaking other things.

```sql
alter schema "Supervisorrrrr" rename to public;
```

If you want to move out your things from `public`, run a series of [`alter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)s:

```sql
create schema "Supervisorrrrr";
alter table public.your_table set schema "Supervisorrrrr";
alter view public.your_view set schema "Supervisorrrrr";
```

To keep things tidy (-er/-ish) in the future, you could

- Require your users to always use schema-qualified names, which might be inconvenient
- [Create a dedicated, private schema for each of your users](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATTERNS), named after their usernames. That way by default, their stuff ends up in their schema, without interfering with others in the Wild West Re`public`.
- If you're working alone and/or that's a throwaway GIS lab you don't wont to tinker too much with, only clean it up a bit, next time you (or others) want to build and modify structures

  ```sql
  create schema your_new_schema_for_new_stuff;
  set search_path = your_new_schema_for_new_stuff, public;
  ```

  That way subsequent queries will target the new schema by default, without littering `public`, while still being able to refer to types and functions in `public`.
- Do not operate as a superuser by default - not in the DB, not in your operating system, not anywhere.

Comment: "*It's best to create a dedicated, private schema for each of your users, named after their usernames*" - I'd say that very much depends on their use case. I don't know how common that pattern is, personally I've never come across it - most (web) applications I've seen have multiple users accessing the same schema(s).

Comment: @Bergi That's straight from the doc, linked under there. In most web apps you typically access predefined, shared database entities and that's not in any way prevented by providing each user with their own schema. Still, in a web app setup, those are mostly service users, running only predefined DML/DQL on those pre-existing structures - without any need for a schema to build and modify new structures in. OP's setup seems to be some kind of a GIS lab, where I would expect human, manual operators run a lot of possibly conflicting DDL/DML/DCL, in which case they could use the isolation.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the link to the docs, but it says "*There are a few [different] usage patterns easily supported*", whereas your answer makes it sound like "*It's [always] best to …*".

Comment: "*OP's setup seems to be some kind of a GIS lab*" - that's a reasonable assumption, but not explicitly stated in the question, so you may want to qualify the recommendation in your answer.

Comment: @Bergi Fair point. Although I didn't mean it to sound like *it's the law*, if reading this you were under an impression I implied the *[always]*, then it's worth rephrasing on my part - I added an edit to make it clearer it's a recommendation for this case, rather than any case.

Comment: Thank you so much good people,

changing back Schema name back to the original **public** brought back my data, and everything is now working perfectly!!